# Behavior of omp_get_max_threads in parallel regions

Tags: c, openmp

I compile this bit of code on Snow Leopard and linux and I get different results.  On Snow leopard, the first call of omp_get_max_threads returns 2, which is my number of cores, while the second returns 1.  On linux, both calls return 4, which is my number of cores.  I think Linux has the correct behavior, am I right?  Are both correct and I just have a misunderstanding of this function?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main() {
  printf(" In a serial region; max threads are : %d\n", omp_get_max_threads());
#pragma omp parallel
{
  #pragma omp master
  printf(" In a parallel region; max threads are : %d\n", omp_get_max_threads());
}
}
```

Mac output:

```
 In a serial region; max threads are : 2
 In a parallel region; max threads are : 1
```

Linux output:

```
 In a serial region; max threads are : 4
 In a parallel region; max threads are : 4
```

Comment: Which gcc are you using? 4.0 or 4.2?

Comment: Mac: gcc version 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646) (dot 1)
Linux: gcc version 4.4.1 [gcc-4_4-branch revision 150839] (SUSE Linux) 


Actually, doing some more testing, RHEL 5 running gcc version 4.1.1 20070105 (Red Hat 4.1.1-52) gives the behavior I described for mac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this call is well specified in the openmp spec.  linux has the correct behavior here.
with that being said, you are in a master region which is effectively serial and fhe the main thread, so the num threads call is explainable.  if you arent tied to pure c I would encourage you to look at the c++ tbb library and particularly the ppl subset, you will find more generality and composability like for nested parallelism.   I'm on myphone so I apologize for typos here.

Answer (score 1):

With Apple-supplied gcc 4.2 [gcc version 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5566)] on Leopard, I get the same results as you (except that my MacBook has fewer cores).

```
In a serial region; max threads are : 2
In a parallel region; max threads are : 1
```

Ditto for 4.3.4 from MacPorts.

However, with gcc 4.4.2 and 4.5.0 20091231 (experimental) from MacPorts, on the same computer I get:

```
In a serial region; max threads are : 2
In a parallel region; max threads are : 2
```

It looks like this isn't a Mac versus Linux issue, but due to the gcc version.

P.S.  OpenMP can do nested parallelism.

Answer (score 0):

Just a reminder, there is a forum devoted just to OpenMP, and read by the developers of OpenMP as well as OpenMP experts world wide. It's over at the official OpenMP website: http://openmp.org/forum

Great place to ask questions like this, and to find a lot of other resources at openmp.org

Answer (score 0):

Weird. I always get the expected behaviour (using 4.2.1, build 5646 dot 1) with OS X 10.6.2:

On my Mac Pro

```
 In a serial region; max threads are : 8
 In a parallel region; max threads are : 8
```

and on my iMac

```
In a serial region; max threads are : 2
In a parallel region; max threads are : 2
```

Must be something else going on here. Compiling with just?

```
gcc fname.c -fopenmp
```